# Creating legend and defining colours for facetwrap with multiple geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm creating a faceted plot of each sampling point, and trying to show four variables - a bar (species abundance at each sampling point), a line for water depth at the sampling point, another line for river height (measured elsewhere), and symbols for treatment intervention.

My problem is I can't seem to get the legend to show all the variables. I've included colour in the aesthetics for the geom_point, so that shows up, but I can't get the geom_lines into the legend. How can I get all four geoms represented in the legend?

Also, I'd like a third y-axis, as currently the grey line (river height) isn't represented on the y-axis at all. I've researched this and don't think there is away of adding a third y-axis, but if I'm missing something would be grateful for advice on that too.

This is the code (now updated  based on comments)

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = dat2_site, aes(y=count_l_site, x=date, fill=f_grp), position="stack",stat="identity") +
  geom_line(data = dat2_site, aes(y=2*water_depth, x=date)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(dat2_site, control_previous_week=='yes'), aes(y=-5, x=date), size = 3, shape = 17, colour = 'black', ) +
  geom_line(data = dat_twyford, aes(x = date, y=50*value), linetype = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~site,ncol=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), strip.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), panel.border = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = NA)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits=c(-5, 100), sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2, name = 'Water depth (cm)')) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels =  "%b") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),axis.title=element_text(size=12),legend.text = element_text(size=8))+
  labs(x="Date",y="Number of larvae per litre", colour = 'Control')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols_f_grps)+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')+
  theme(legend.text.align = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to include colour or shape in the aesthetics, but as you’ve discovered R doesn’t always play ball.

There is more information on this here https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/manual-legends-ggplot2/

I’ve had a go at editing your code. I suggest you subset the data before building the ggplot, for example like this:

```
dat2_site_y <-
  dat2_site %>%
  filter(control_previous_week == 'yes')
```

Once you’ve done that you can build the ggplot as normal, and using scale_colour_identity to define the line colour, name, and label. You can also add scale_shape to add the control symbol.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = dat2_site, aes(y=count_l_site, x=date, fill=f_grp), position="stack",stat="identity") +.    geom_line(data = dat2_site, aes(y=2*water_depth, x=date, colour = 'blue')) +
  geom_point(data = dat2_site_y, aes(y=-5, x=date, shape = control_previous_week), size = 3) +
  geom_line(data = dat_twyford2, aes(x = date, y=100*value, colour = 'grey')) +
  facet_wrap(~site,ncol=3, scales = 'free_y') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols_f_grps, name = 'Functional group') +
  scale_colour_identity(name = '', breaks = c('blue', 'grey'), labels = c('Water depth', 'River height'), guide = 'legend') +
  scale_shape(name = 'line', breaks = c('yes'), labels = c('Control'))
```

I haven’t been able to run it, as Phil has said below you we would need a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the data argument in the `ggplot` function if you plan on utilizing different data frames to populate your plot. Instead move the data argument to each geom that it relies on, and it should work. I can't provide an example of the output as your data is not provided and your code is therefore not reproducible, but it would look something like this:

```
ggplot(aes(x=date)) +
  geom_bar(data = dat2_site, aes(y=count_l_site, fill=f_grp), position="stack",stat="identity")+
  geom_line(data = dat2_site, aes(y=2*water_depth), colour = 'blue')  +
  geom_point(data = subset(dat2_site, control_previous_week=='yes'), aes(y=-5, shape = control_previous_week, colour = 'yes'), size = 3, shape = 17, colour = 'black') +
  geom_line(data = dat_twyford, aes(x = date, y=50*value, colour = value), linetype = 1)
```

Note that the last line you had the colour argument used twice, and that within the `aes()` function you have to name the variable being mapped without quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated the code as you suggested, although I had to move the x aesthetics into each line, as I had an error message. I will paste the updated code. I've now just got the x, y, and fill within the aes, which I think means I will only get the fill in the legend. How can I get the other datasets represented in the legend as well?

Comment: I've been playing with some, and simplified the code a little, but I'm still not able to show the 2x geom_line and the geom_point in the legend. I think its because there is no subset of those geoms, ie only one line in each varaible and just one group in the points ( as I have used a subset of the data to only plot the 'yes' values). Would really appreciate further advice on this, as I need to label those lines & symbols.

Comment: It's really hard to help further without a reproducible example to work from - this can be from any data out there that closely resembles yours. One advice i would give is, if possible, to combine the data all into one data frame that is in long format, with a variable indicating which should be used to map on fills and colours.